# Schengen visa (Germany) travel insurance valid long than trip

Tags: schengen-visas, insurance

Will there be an issue if my travel in the Schengen area is December 5-15 and I have a travel insurance (50,000 Euro coverage) for December 5-25?

Comment: I dont see any issue as you are covered for your travel duration. Why do you think there will be an issue?

Comment: purely one man's opinion - nobody will even notice this. You're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

The requested insurance for the Schengen visa is a minimum, you can be insured for more or for longer or even both at the same time.

There will not be a problem with your longer insurance.

Comment: Thank you so much willeke. One more question. I was denied a visa due to insufficient funds, now I am planning to deposit a little more money in my account, remove 2 countries of my chosen destination (Greece and Italy) and keep Germany in my itinerary, I’m going to apply in Germany Embassy again. Is this doable?

Comment: That is a completely different question and one I have no answer for. And it is a question that does not fit this site, as it is opinion or whatever the visa officer decides. (But if you put more money in your account, also include proof of where the money comes from.)

Answer (score 1):

My stay in the Schengen is from Dec 4th to Dec 6th. However I have got an insurance for 13 days. I am not sure if you are asking this question from a visa application point of view, but I got my visa successfully from Austrian embassy using this insurance.